# Limiting Subclass Field Type

Tags: java

Seems like a painfully simple problem I cannot find an answer to.
Let's say there's a box:

```
public class Box {
    Object contents;
    ...
}
```

I want to make a subclass of Box that will only store a subtype of Object, like a String:

```
public class StringBox extends Box {
    String contents;
    //added fields/methods
    ... 
}
```

But that shadows the contents in StringBox's parent, which is not what I want to do. I could use an if statement or something, but that seems like a poor workaround. I also know that one could use generics and only have a Box< T> class, but I would like to have subclasses with extra functionality. And I do not know of abstract fields either, so I am at a bit of a loss.

If it's not clear, I'm looking for a good way to limit a field inherited by a super class to a particular subtype. If I am missing something obvious, or a better way to do things, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I do not know of abstract fields either

There's no such thing as `abstract` field. Only methods (an classes, respectively) can be `abstract`.

> I also know that one could use generics and only have a `Box<T>` class, but I would like to have subclasses with extra functionality.

A generic `Box<T>` could be actually your best friend in this case. Also, if your `Box` class just exposes some abstraction, you could just transform in to a generic interface:

```
public interface Box<T> {
    T getContent();
}

public class StringBox implements Box<String> {

    private String contents;

    String getContent();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that kind of implementation might be a possibility, but I could not find any examples. One quick clarification before I wrap this up: If I make StringBox extend Box<String> (which I am making a class here), is "contents" now a String inherited from Box<String>?

Comment: If you leave the `Box` to be a class with a `T` member, then yes.